# Skyrim will not launch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I fired up Steam to launch Skyrim.  Now when I press play from the splash screen it just disappears and then shows the splash screen again.

How can I see what is going wrong?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you verified the game integrity? (Steam right-click option)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skyrim launcher keeps prompting for elevation, but never launches](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/skyrim-launcher-keeps-prompting-for-elevation-but-never-launches)

Comment: @NickT Different problem, same resolution.

Comment: How is the problem different at all, the UAC settings may be different, but other than that it's the exact same symptoms.

Comment: @NickT - I was not getting elevation prompts and I tried running in admin mode too.

Comment: Your computer could be configured differently for UAC.  How did you run a game in "admin mode"; if you used a Steam shortcut (e.g. on the desktop or in your start menu), it would just run the client with elevated privileges, not the game that it in turn launches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried verifying the game's integrity? It sounds like something might have gotten corrupted, and rather than crashing, the launcher is recovering (though not giving you an error message to let you know something's wrong).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: After doing this, my Up and Down look sensitivity was shot.  (Took me pulling my mouse down a lot of times to move just a tiny bit.)  I adjusted  my fMouseHeadingYScale to 1.3200 and it seemed to work beter.  (Note I had modified this previously.)

Comment: @Vaccano There was [another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39577/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-steam-from-overwriting-my-configuration-changes-when-i) about Skyrim updates messing with your configs. I'd follow the answer there to prevent this from happening again.